Why does this interchangeably printed code cause a deadlock?
This is a piece of code that uses Go's channel to interchangeably print 1 to 10, but writing it this way causes a deadlock.
func main() {
    oddCh := make(chan struct{})
    evenCh := make(chan struct{})
    done := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        defer close(evenCh)
        for i := 1; i < 10; i += 2 {
            <-oddCh
            fmt.Println(i)
            evenCh <- struct{}{}
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        defer close(done)
        for i := 2; i <= 10; i += 2 {
            <-evenCh
            fmt.Println(i)
            oddCh <- struct{}{}
            if i == 10 {
                close(oddCh)
                break
            }
        }
    }()

    oddCh <- struct{}{}

    <-done
}

Outputs:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
    D:/Gocode/alternateprint/main.go:34 +0x125

goroutine 7 [chan send]:
main.main.func2()
    D:/Gocode/alternateprint/main.go:24 +0xcb
created by main.main in goroutine 1
    D:/Gocode/alternateprint/main.go:19 +0x105

I think wake up the second goroutine after the first goroutine executes to i=9, then the second goroutine executes to I =10 and prints 10, writes a signal to oddCh, and then shuts down oddCh. That's not a big problem, but it does cause a deadlock.Then I just switched the order of the two paragraphs:
if i == 10 {
    close(oddCh)
    break
}

and
oddCh <- struct{}{}

After the swap there is no deadlock and the output is normal.

In final i loop, G2 oddCh had write,but no read chan.(G1 already end)
If you updated to
        if i == 10 {
            close(oddCh)
            break
        } else {
            oddCh <- struct{}{}
        }

will no deadlock.

The reason is that after the even goroutine produces 9it exits. Note: it was the only reader for oddCh.
When the odd gorutine produces 10, it writes to oddCh. But the even goroutine has already exited, and oddCh block until a new read from that channel. Go runtime identifies the deadlock:

main waits for <- done: there is no other waiting goroutine, that can write there,
odd waits for odd<-: there is no goroutine that can read from that channel.

Use buffering
To prevent this deadlock add buffering to the channels:
    oddCh := make(chan Message, 1)
    evenCh := make(chan Message, 1)

If a channel has some free space in the buffer, then channel send wouldn't block.
Proof: https://go.dev/play/p/ya266_Xa0rQ
Keep the reader
Alternative solution: even should read the last odd number
    go func() {
        defer close(evenCh)
        for i := 1; i < 10; i += 2 {
            <-oddCh
            fmt.Println(i)
            evenCh <- struct{}{}
        }
        <-oddCh
    }()

Proof: https://go.dev/play/p/pLZQPcSz4X1
Use non-blocking send
Plan C: use non-blocking operations
type BlockingError struct{}

func (be BlockingError) Error() string {
    return "Timeout exceeded"
}

func NonBlockSend[T any](ch chan<- T, v T, dt time.Duration) error {
    select {
    case ch <- v:
        return nil
    case <-time.After(dt):
        return BlockingError{}
    }
}

This function waits until either the channel accepts a new value, or timeout expires.
    go func() {
        defer close(done)
        for i := 2; i <= 10; i += 2 {
            <-evenCh
            fmt.Println(i)
            err := NonBlockSend(oddCh, struct{}{}, time.Millisecond)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("ERROR: oddCh is blocked")
            }
            if i == 10 {
                close(oddCh)
                break
            }
        }
    }()

Output: https://go.dev/play/p/HpIta6dc3tA
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
ERROR: oddCh is blocked


Plan D: Use non-buffer channel
https://go.dev/play/p/dZrXgwKw76M

@yvluwang update the second goroutine to loop over 10: https://go.dev/play/p/POSvgB9H6oC : deadlock

Yes, so we should fix the first goroutine to loop over 10 too. :)
https://go.dev/play/p/7j3xwU2Y2Uw
